# The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found for PCRE

Tags: homebrew, pcre

I'm trying to install [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). The brew installation halts at the PCRE installation, so I ran the command independently.

What should be done to properly install PCRE for Brew?

[image]

Comment: Yo bro did you end up finding a solution to this issue? Im experiencing the exact same problem! Its so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too.
Then I browsed the download url. `https://sourceforge.mirrorservice.org/p/pc/pcre/pcre/`

[The screen shoot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKFTD.png)

It shows that here is no 8.38 source file, 404 was happened.

So I decide to install pcre by source code

- `http://www.pcre.org` download source code
- decompress the file and move into it and execute cmd

  - ./configure
  - make && make install

Comment: Now brew install pcre can work. The source file was uploaded.